# CSS3 element1~element2 Selector (opposite)

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```html
<div class="example1"> 123 </div>
<span class="example2"> 1234 </span>
```

I would like to set background-color to red `.example1` only if there is `.example2` after it.

This looks very similiar to what I am asking for, but I need opposite:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp

Comment: You can't with CSS. It's one of the reasons for the word "cascading" in CSS.

Comment: You can do it with JS only.

Comment: @Rob: The word "cascading" has nothing to do with the order of elements.

Comment: @BoltClock No it doesn't but we're not talking about DOM element order.